# Group categories in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset

```
Call.reason <- c("Binnen zichttermijn", "Buiten zichttermijn", "Reparatie", "dvd hoesjes", "Technische ondersteuning", "Retour koop ongedaan maken", "Digitaal", "Kobo")
Count <- c(67452, 47279, 38530, 2554, 34044, 12190, 22102, 1234)
Categorie <- c("Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Defect", "Digitaal", "Digitaal", "Digitaal", "Digitaal")
df <- data.frame(Call.reason, Count, Categorie)
```

I now create a graph from this data doing:

```
p6 <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=Categorie, x=Call.reason, y=Count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This works fine. However when you plot the categories are mixed. I want to have the defect and digitaal. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, this has been asked many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to order the factor `Call.reason` because the default order is alphabetical:

```
df$Call.reason <- factor(df$Call.reason, levels = df$Call.reason)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = Categorie, x = Call.reason, y = Count)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Henk Straten if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.